# WPF MVVM Linked Views

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datacontext

I need some help regarding my first MVVM WPF application.  I want to link two views on my main window.  Here's the situation:

I have for instance these two viewmodels:

```
- PersonDetailViewModel
- PersonListViewModel
```

PersonListViewModel contains :
 - an `ObservableCollection` of `PersonDetailViewModels` called People
 - one `PersonDetailViewMode`l which is accessible through a public property called `"SelectedPerson"`

I also have created two views:
`PersonListView`, which lists all persons in a datagrid.
`PersonDetailView`, which is simply a bunch of labels and textboxes bound to the `viewmodel` `PersonDetailViewModel`.

I want to use these two together on my MainWindow.  But I have no idea how the make this work!
Here's what I have so far:

PersonListView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="DSS.View.PersonListView"
         ...
         xmlns:myViewModels="clr-namespace:DSS.ViewModel">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <myViewModels:PersonListViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgPeople" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ColumnWidth="*" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"> 
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="PersonId" Binding="{Binding PersonId}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Firstname" Binding="{Binding Firstname}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lastname" Binding="{Binding Lastname}"/>
            ...
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

PersonDetailView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DSS_CV.View.PersonDetailView"
         ...
         xmlns:myViewModels="clr-namespace:DSS.ViewModel">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <myViewModels:PersonDetailViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>        
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>... </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>...</Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Firstname:</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtFirstName" Text="{Binding Path=Firstname}"></TextBox>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Lastname:</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtLastName" Text="{Binding Path=Lastname}"></TextBox>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">Birthdate:</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtBirtDate" Text="{Binding Path=DateOfBirth}"></TextBox>
    ...        
    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
        <Button>Update</Button>
        <Button>Insert As New</Button>
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

Now, I would like to combine/link these usercontrols in one window so they work together in a way that selecting a row from the datagrid allows to edit the details in the other usercontrol.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="DSS_CV.MainWindow"
    ...
    xmlns:myViews="clr-namespace:DSS_CV.View">
    <Grid>
        <myViews:PersonListView x:Name="dgPersons" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <myViews:PersonDetailView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding dgPersons.SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
     </Grid>
</Window>
```

`INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented everywhere in my classes and the selecting a different row in `PersonListView` updates its property `SelectedPerson` correctly.  Now I do not see how I can bind the datacontext of `PersonDetailView` to that `SelectedPerson`.   If anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<myViews:PersonDetailView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding dgPersons.SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

To

```
<myViews:PersonDetailView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedPerson ElementName=dgPersons, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: No problem! If it solves your issue, you can mark it as solved.